# Intent. Правильное получение данных из Активити

Tags: android, activity, android-intent

У меня 2 активити. В главном активити два блока в которых по 2 TextView. При нажатии на блоков открывается второе активити с ListView и Со странами и городами и если кликнуть по Item, то эти данные(Страна и город) должны появится на TextView блока которого нажали... Проблема в том, что при выборе у обеих TextView значения одинаковые, то есть оба - города! Как решить проблему?

**Первый Активити**

**Два блока**

```
        case R.id.linearFrom:
            Intent intentFrom = new Intent(this, LocationActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(intentFrom, 1);
            break;

        case R.id.linearTo:
            Intent intentTo = new Intent(this, LocationActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(intentTo, 2);
            break;

        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
          if (data == null) {return;}

          if(requestCode == 1){
          tvFrom.setText(data.getStringExtra(LocationActivity.FROM_ANSWER));
          tvSubFrom.setText(data.getStringExtra(LocationActivity.SUB_FROM_ANSWER));
        }
          if(requestCode == 2){
          tvTo.setText(data.getStringExtra(LocationActivity.TO_ANSWER));
        tvSubTo.setText(data.getStringExtra(LocationActivity.SUB_TO_ANSWER));
        }
        }
```

**Второй активити**

```
    public static final String FROM_ANSWER = "Answer for FROM";
    public static final String SUB_FROM_ANSWER = "Answer for FROM";
    public static final String TO_ANSWER = "Answer for TO";
    public static final String SUB_TO_ANSWER = "Answer for TO";

    String cityWithCountry = country.getCities() + ", " + country.getCountries();

    Intent intent1 = new Intent();

    intent.putExtra(SUB_FROM_ANSWER, cityWithCountry);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, intent1);

    intent.putExtra(SUB_TO_ANSWER, cityWithCountry);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, intent1);

    finish();
```

Comment: У вас в константах строки одинаковые.

Comment: Мне почему-то кажется, что мой способ неправильный ибо напрягает количество константов. Может есть и другой способ, если есть пожалуйста можете описать...

Comment: А зачем два раза присваивать результат 
setResult(RESULT_OK, intent1);
setResult(RESULT_OK, intent1);

Answer (score 1):

```
public static final String FROM_ANSWER = "Answer_for_FROM";
public static final String SUB_FROM_ANSWER = "Answer_for_FROM2";
public static final String TO_ANSWER = "Answer_for_TO";
public static final String SUB_TO_ANSWER = "Answer_for_TO2";
```